# Multilevel Latent Profile Analysis in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a multilevel latent profile analysis, where Level 2 classes are based on Level 1 ratings. I was originally planning on running the analyses in MPlus but I've since realized I don't have the correct version of the software to run multilevel models.

Can anyone recommend a package in R where I would be able to run multilevel LPA models with data where individuals are nested in teams?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: this is more a question for cross validated